# Having a problem to send message to gmail from our mail server

Tags: server, mysql, postfix, dovecot, mail-server

We use Ubuntu Server and in a days I have installed and configured Postfix+Dovecot+MySQL as it is explained [here](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze). From that tutorial I escaped creating certificates and antispam application. Right now it works good but when I try to send an email to GMail I am getting back my email with following content:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; ns1
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 19FDD1EA1826
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; johnsmith@index.tj
Arrival-Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2011 14:05:35 +0500 (TJT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; johnsmith@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;johnsmith@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [217.11.179.46       1] Our system has
   detected an unusual rate of 550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from
   your IP address. To protect our 550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from
   your IP address has been blocked. 550-5.7.1 Please visit
   http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review 550 5.7.1 our Bulk
   Email Senders Guidelines. w3si6844977eej.200

Our system has
   detected an unusual rate of 550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from
   your IP address.
```

I tried to send to another outside domain and my email had been sent successfully. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem adding `postmaster` email account to our domain. It was just one guess of my friend and I don't know why but it started to work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your IP address was being used by a spammer before and Google blacklisted it, or that your system is sending email too quickly. I would follow the recommendations listed at http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html as they mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem might be that the client you are using is not setting the Message-ID header. To fix that with dovecot use:

```
always_add_missing_headers=yes
```

Funny thing is, in my case it was the GMail mobile client for android which has this behaviour and failed to send mails to *@gmail.com